# Exiting the Rails console after an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been use the rails console for testing and learning purposes and when I encounter an error I cannot exit anymore using the "Control + C" command. Is there another command to exit? 
This is what the console looks like when I try to do this:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :026 > user.find_by_name("Test")
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_by_name' for #<User:0x00000100f991a0>
    from /Users/easierlife/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/activemodel-3.0.7/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:367:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/easierlife/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:46:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):26
    from /Users/easierlife/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /Users/easierlife/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/easierlife/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :027 > ^C^C^C^C^C
```

Thanks

Comment: This question is clearly related to part of the process of developing Rails apps and is not a SuperUser candidate, IMHO.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You could try:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Typing `exit`, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks - the CTRL D did it for me!

Answer (score 6):

if the above fails, open another terminal then:

```
ps aux | grep ruby
```

you'll get something like:

```
username      917  52.7  0.4  2455912  17484 s000  R+    9:22AM   0:01.13 /Users/yourusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby script/rails c
```

you'll need the "917" id:

```
sudo kill -9 917
```

(also i think this should be migrated to superuser.com)

Answer (score 3):

You can come out from console screen by simply typing 'exit' on console and pressing 'enter'.

but today i faced some weird issue, when i displayed all records available in table which exceeds console screen size

then i pressed **enter** button until we reach end of records, now if we press "Control + C", "Control + Z" and exit commands nothing worked for me.

I get stuck on console screen and screen was not allowing me to do anything.

Finally got Solution!!!!

```
press 'q' key
```

BooM!!

Now every thing normal :)